# How prevent PhpStorm 10.0.3 insert two empty lines after php close tag

Tags: php, line, phpstorm

After write constructions like this - `<?=123?>` and press enter after it, PhpStorm draw two lines instead of one.

I cannot find settings that adjust this behavior.

PhpStorm version - 10.0.3. On PhpStorm version 8.0 I don't have same problem.

Comment: what technologies PHP do you use ?

Comment: @darkomen, in this case I need to insert some PHP varialbe into my template (Template without any parsers, simple `<?=$variable?>`)

Comment: I already understand but lot of engine template php exist with lot of tools php exist for generate lot of code. We don't know your technical environnement.

Comment: @darkomen, oh, now I think understand the question. There is no any unuausal plugins that can add extra row after pressing Enter key. That behavior appears when I enable "PHP" plugin for PhpStorm. If plugin is disabled - there is no highlight and no problem )